# Kähler differentials in an inseparable field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, positive-characteristic

Let $L/K$ be a finite (or, more generally, algebraic) field extension. It is easy to show that if $L/K$ is separable then the $L$-vector space $\Omega_{L/K}$ of relative Kähler differentials is zero. Apparently the converse is also true (at least for finite extensions). It is set right at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1115265/184547) as an "easy exercise", but I'm really struggling to show it. I suppose one way of possibly doing it is assuming the extension is inseparable and exhibiting a nontrivial $K$-derivation $L\to L$ to obtain

$$  \dim_L \Omega_{L/K}=\dim_L \Omega_{L/K}^\vee = \dim_L\text{Der}_K (L,L)>0,$$
 but I can't come up with one. Can anyone help?

Comment: I mean, the easiest way of doing this is to say that smoothness is equivalent to locally finite presentation+flat+locally free differentials of correct rank, but that seems somewhat cheating. Some more elementary ideas are as follows:

1) Reduce to purely inseparable. Reduce to primitive purely inseparable where the result is obvious.

2) Use connection between differentials and trace pairing, and the fact that the trace pairing is zero if extension is not separable.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I've not seen a link between differentials and the trace pairing (although I've only been thinking about differentials for a couple of days!). Would you be able to expand upon what you mean by this connection?

Comment: see QingLiu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curve", Chapter 6.1.1, Lemma 1.13, which states that if $K/k$ is finite, then $K/k$ is separable if and only if $\Omega_{K/k}^1=0$.